# Mongoose display with relationships

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

I have three tables 'cases', 'partners' and 'casepartners' with the following structure:

> **cases**: id,subject,description
>
> **partners**: id,name,address
>
> **casepartners**:case,partner,createdAt

I would like to list all cases by also showing for each case, casepartners records where the case id is the same.

I am using this code:

```
Case.find().sort('-created').exec(function (err, cases) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(cases);
        }
    });
```

It shows all cases fine, but I would like to also show for each case object a list of **casepartners** for that case id...

Let's say a few partners got subscribed to the same case and I would like to list all of those partners or just count how many partners got subscribed to that case.

I am using Angularjs to list all cases using the ng-repeat but I am kinda confused if I have to make a separate call to show casepartners records for each case within ng-repeat or attach this in the same function by using some kind of .populate() or something else with the entity relationships.

These are the models defined:

```
var CaseSchema = new Schema({
    subject: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Subject cannot be blank'
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    customer: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer'
    },
    category: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }
});

var CasePartnerSchema = new Schema({
    case: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Case'
    },
    partner: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Partner'
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var PartnerSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible I would recommend redefining your collections (tables) since having a CasePartner collection is a little redundant.

Instead of having a case and casePartner collection, I would recommend you only have a case collection and then have an array of partners inside of that collection.

Your schema would then look like this:

```
var CaseSchema = new Schema({
    partners: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Partner'
    }],
    subject: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Subject cannot be blank'
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    customer: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer'
    },
    category: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }
});
```

Your find would then look like this:

```
Case
  .find({})
  .sort('-created')
  //.populate() populates all info from the partnersSchema for each partner
  .populate('partners')
  .exec(function(err, cases) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(cases);
    }
  });
```

Check out [this](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) for more on MongoDB schema design.

Comment: This seems to be the best approach.

Comment: how would .find() looks like in this case? at this moment it just shows all cases, but for sure there should be some kind of where stm here?

Answer (score 1):

try [mongoose-reverse-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-reverse-populate).  There is a way called populate in mongoose but that helps you when you are first searching caseparters and populate case types . however what you wanted is  kind of reverse of that .

Comment: If you liked the answer then please accept it , not just up vote.!!

Comment: I havent yet tested to see if this works, let check it and if it works I will accept ur answer...